# Only show header if section number > 0

Tags: header-footer, conditionals, fancyhdr, counters

The current section name + chapter.section number is shown in the header. This is normal behaviour (what I want).

Example:

[image]

How can I remove the header text, if there is no section on the page. The following example illustrate my problem. The header is "1.0" but I want to show nothing.

Example:

[image]

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\makebox[2cm][r]{}{}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\hspace*{0.2cm}\thesection}


\begin{document}

\chapter{An example chapter}

\blindtext[25]

\section{An example section}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `fancyhdr` with `scrbook` is not recommended. However, here's a solution: issue the `\thesection` command within `\markright`. Note that `\markright` takes only one argument (whereas `\markboth` needs two).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{#1\ \thesection}%
}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{An example chapter}

\lipsum[1-20]

\section{An example section}

\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```