# How to define a page number showing the current ((sub)sub)section?

Tags: sectioning, page-numbering

I try to print the section (with (sub)subsections) in the page foot. For this I
defined a new page number. It works fine on the first four, but not on the last
page... The goal is to have ``Section x'' printed on every page, where x is
precisely the number of the enclosing ((sub)sub)section.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

% page number (omitting trailing zeros)
\newcommand{\mypagenumber}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
      \ifnum\value{section}=0
        % nothing
      \else
        Section~\thesection% e.g. 2
      \fi
    \else
      Section~\thesubsection% e.g. 2.1
    \fi
  \else
    Section~\thesubsubsection% e.g. 2.1.3
  \fi
}

\ofoot{\mypagenumber}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\clearpage
\subsection{Subsection}
\clearpage
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\clearpage
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\clearpage
\section{Section}
This page should only show ``Section 2'' (not ``Section 2.0.2'')
\end{document}
```

Here is an update that takes care of the problem that Christian addressed. Still, it requires that sections are not directly followed by subsubsections.

```
\newcommand{\mypagenumber}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
      \ifnum\value{section}=0
        % nothing
      \else
        Section~\thesection% e.g. 2
      \fi
    \else
      Section~\thesubsection% e.g. 2.1
    \fi
  \else
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
      Section~\thesection% e.g. 2
    \else
      Section~\thesubsubsection% e.g. 2.1.3
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

Comment: Your `\ifnum` statements do not catch the case when **subsection = 0** if **subsubsection \neq 0**. The reason is, that the subsubsection counter is reset when a new subsection is used, not by a new section. One way to cope with this, would to remove the resetting of subsubsection from subsection and shift it to section, but then resetting would fail, when a new subsection is to be written.

Comment: indeed, adding this case "solves" it (without requiring eboxtools). But see my comment below, it's still not always the same number as the current enclosing section uses.

Comment: What ((sub-)sub-)section do you want printed when there is more than one of them on a specific page? And what to do with pages that do not contain any ((sub-)sub-)section?

Comment: Hi Werner. When there are more than one ((sub)sub)section on a page, print the last one (most advanced number). When there are none, print the last one. If there is no last one (say, at the beginning of the document), then don't print anything (this is my "nothing" case above). Note: all of these cases correspond to the rule "print whatever the current section number actually is".

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173858/subsubsection-as-page-number-interference-with-biblatexs-heading-bibintoc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is taken from [Only show header if section number > 0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167505/5764). You can use

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{#1\ \thesection}%
}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{#1\ \thesubsection}%
}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{#1\ \thesubsubsection}%
}

\ofoot{\rightmark}
```

This will display the sectional unit (passed as `#1` above). If you want only `Section`, then substitute all `#1` for `Section`.

The use of `\rightmark` avoids a problem when the page-breaking algorithm is called into play at the start of the sectional unit. This could cause counters to be incremented on the page where the section does not end up eventually. Using `\rightmark` with the included sectional representations (`\thesection`, `\thesubsection` and `\thesubsubsection`) circumvents this issue.

Comment: If the last section starts with a subsection, then the foot shows the section, not the subsection. The subsection is only shown on the following pages then. Do you know a solution for this? [or is this even 'desired behavior'?]

Answer (score 2):

I switched from `\ifnum` style to use `\ifnumexpr` from `etoolbox`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\clearscrheadfoot



% page number (omitting trailing zeros)

% This uses the direct counter formatting, but should not be applied,
% The checking of counter values is the same as in \mypagenumber, where
% the formatting commands \the... are used.

\newcommand{\myotherpagenumber}{%
Section~
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsubsection}}{0}{% subsubsection = 0 then remove subsubsection counter from output
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{% subsection = 0, then remove subsection from output
  \arabic{section}}{% No, subsection \neq 0
  \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}
}{% No subsubsection \neq 0, now check again for subsection = 0
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{% Yes, subsection = 0, remove it from output
  \arabic{section}}{% No, subsubsection \neq 0, show all three counter values. 
  \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}}
}% End of outer \ifnumequal{subsubsection}...
}% End of command. 


\newcommand{\mypagenumber}{%
Section~
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsubsection}}{0}{%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{\thesection}{\thesubsection}%
}{\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{\thesection}{\thesubsubsection}}
}% End of command




\ofoot{\mypagenumber}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\clearpage
\subsection{Subsection}
\clearpage
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\clearpage
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\clearpage
\section{Section}
This page should only show ``Section 2'' (not ``Section 2.0.2'')
\end{document}
```

[image: Entire page of the second section without subsection and subsubsections]

**Edit**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\clearscrheadfoot

% Save old \thesubsubsection command 

\let\LaTeXStandardTheSubSubsection\thesubsubsection
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{% sub = 0
\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsubsection}}{%
\LaTeXStandardTheSubSubsection}%
}%

% Save old \thesubsection command 
\let\LaTeXStandardTheSubsection\thesubsection
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{% drop sub = 0
}{%
\LaTeXStandardTheSubsection}%
}%



\newcommand{\myotherpagenumber}{%
Section~
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsubsection}}{0}{% subsubsection = 0 then remove subsubsection counter from output
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{% subsection = 0, then remove subsection from output
  \arabic{section}}{% No, subsection \neq 0
  \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}
}{% No subsubsection \neq 0, now check again for subsection = 0
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{% Yes, subsection = 0, remove it from output
  \arabic{section}}{% No, subsubsection \neq 0, show all three counter values. 
  \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}}
} 
} % End of command.

\newcommand{\mypagenumber}{%
Section~
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsubsection}}{0}{%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{\thesection}{\thesubsection}%
}{\ifnumequal{\number\value{subsection}}{0}{\thesection}{\thesubsubsection}}
}% End of command




\ofoot{\Huge \mypagenumber}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section Number \textcolor{blue}{1}}
\subsubsection{ \textcolor{red}{I am actually a subsubsection and not a subsection ;-) -- my number is 1.1}}
\clearpage
\subsection{True first Subsection \textcolor{green}{1.1}}
\clearpage
\subsubsection{\textcolor{yellow}{True first subsubsection below 1.1}}
\clearpage
\subsubsection{\textcolor{yellow}{True second subsubsection below 1.1}}
%\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\clearpage
\section{Section}
This page should only show ``Section 2'' (not ``Section 2.0.2'')
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for helping. If I directly use a `\subsubsection` after the second `\section`, then the section heading is 2.0.3 (the .3 you explained above -- the counter is not reset by `\section`) but the page number shows "Section 2" (instead of "Section 2.0.3"). Is there any way to get exactly the number from the section head in the page foot/numbering? Hmmm...

Comment: Sure, take your time! I agree that it's not often the case to use a `\subsubsection` after a `\section`, but I'm interested now in how this can be solved :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I don't want to change/modify ((sub)sub)section headings. I simply want whatever numbering is in the header line to show up in the foot as well, be it 2, 2.1, 2.1.3, or 2.0.3.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure to understand what you mean. I simply want the current ((sub)sub)section number printed in the foot on every page. With "current" I mean the very same number that the enclosing ((sub)sub)section uses. If that's "2. ...", then "Section 2", if it's "2.0.3 ...", then "Section 2.0.3". If there has been no `\section` yet, then nothing. Is this feasible? My guess was that LaTeX internally knows the current section and that one simply can "access" this knowledge somehow.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have `\lipsum[1-5]` under the first `\subsection` as it happens to break around the section heading and leads to an incorrect footer on p 2.